# How can I run for_each in terraform on resource group ids combined from several sources?

Tags: terraform

I have started with the following code first:

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "pod_sp" {
    for_each = toset(concat(
        [for component in local.components: tostring(azurerm_resource_group.setup[component].id)],
        [tostring(module.component_remote_state.rg_id)]
        ))

    scope              = each.value
    role_definition_id = data.azurerm_role_definition.contributor.id
    principal_id       = azuread_service_principal.pod_sp.id
}
```

It gave me this:

```
Error: Invalid for_each set argument

  on ..\..\modules\bootstrap\to_inject.tf line 58, in resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "pod_sp":
  58:     for_each = toset(concat(
  59:         [for component in local.components: tostring(azurerm_resource_group.setup[component].id)],
  60:         [tostring(module.component_remote_state.rg_id)]
  61:         ))

The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: "for_each" supports maps
and sets of strings, but you have provided a set containing type dynamic.
```

Then I found https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/22437 and changed my code to:

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "pod_sp" {
    for_each = {for k in concat(
        [for component in local.components: tostring(azurerm_resource_group.setup[component].id)],
        [tostring(module.component_remote_state.rg_id)]
        ): k => k}

    scope              = each.value
    role_definition_id = data.azurerm_role_definition.contributor.id
    principal_id       = azuread_service_principal.pod_sp.id
}
```

Which gave me this:

```
Error: Invalid for_each argument


  on ..\..\modules\bootstrap\to_inject.tf line 59, in resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "pod_sp":
  59:     for_each = {for k in concat(
  60:         [for component in local.components: tostring(azurerm_resource_group.setup[component].id)],
  61:         [tostring(module.component_remote_state.rg_id)]
  62:         ): k => k}

The "for_each" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined
until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances will be created.
To work around this, use the -target argument to first apply only the
resources that the for_each depends on.
```

I do not understand why it says "cannot predict" when `local.components` is very much known:

```
locals {
    components = toset(["web", "data"])
}
```

Is it possible to make it work without the need to run apply with the target first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part that isn't predictable here is the `id` attribute values from `azurerm_resource_group.setup`. Because you're using those as some keys in your map, the result is a map whose set of keys isn't fully known and thus Terraform can't determine how many elements will eventually be in that map and what all of their keys will be.

To make this work, I'd suggest using the strings from `local.components` as the keys instead, since you noted that those are constants in your configuration and thus guaranteed to be known during planning:

```
  for_each = merge(
    { for component in local.components : component => azurerm_resource_group.setup[component].id },
    { "from_remote_state" = module.component_remote_state.rg_id },
  )
```

The above assumes that `local.components` will never contain the string `from_remote_state`, and thus it's safe to use as a special component name to deal with that extra value that doesn't work the same as the others. Since you understand the requirements for that better than I do, you might find a different name more appropriate there, but the general idea here is to produce a map whose keys are all known even if some of the values are not:

```
{
  "web": (known after apply),
  "data": (known after apply),
  "from_remote_state": "<your known rg id from the remote state>",
}
```

From this, Terraform can see how many resource instances you are intending to make and what their addresses must be:

- `azurerm_role_assignment.pod_sp["web"]`
- `azurerm_role_assignment.pod_sp["data"]`
- `azurerm_role_assignment.pod_sp["from_remote_state"]`

Comment: I will test it.